# how do i set MaxStartups for specific user not whole system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

i want to set **MaxStartups** for specific **user** in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
but I cant do something like that since "**Match**" doesn't support **MaxStartups** keyword :

```
Match User test
   MaxStartups 1
```

Comment: `MaxStartups` does not do what you think, it's a configuration to mitigate brute force attacks on ssh

Comment: so is this wrong? the MaxSessions setting in /etc/ssh/sshd_config only limits the number of interactive shell sessions a user can have, but does not limit the number of tunneling sessions. To limit the number of tunneling sessions, you can use the MaxStartups setting in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Try setting MaxStartups to 1 to allow only one concurrent session for the user "test".

Comment: correct, that is wrong

Comment: What is your end goal. What are you trying to achieve.

Comment: i want this :
when i do open 1 ssh tunneling session to server with device 1 with user test
i dont want device 2 be able to do ssh tunneling session to server with user test aswell
but I don't want the roll to apply to all user , only certain users.